# Following a question

Tags: discussion

Does *Mathematica* StackExchange have a way to follow questions. Some times when I look at questions I come across good ideas that I could use for later. However, when I need to refer to them, I can't seem to find the exact question and answer. It would be great if one could mark questions and answers.

Another thing is when there is a question posted that hasn't been answered yet, but I would like to know when it gets answered, is it possible to mark it so that you would get a notification as soon as answers are provided? I am obviously talking about other peoples questions here.

Comment: What do you mean by automatically? :P I do not need to do anything?:P

Comment: You can always favorite a question and it'll be saved to your favorites section. It's that star-looking thing below the downvote sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To star a question as *favorite question*, you can use the icon below the downvote button

> [image]

All favorite questions can be found in [your profile](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8148/alexander?tab=favorites).
The disadvantage of this method is that you only get a long list and you probably don't remember exactly why you marked it from a glance on the title.

The other option is to create a bookmark. This can be done for a specific answer too and not only for questions and the fastest way is to use the `share` button between text and comment-section of a question or an answer.